# Angular 6 - Share Instance of Object between different tabs and browsers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, singleton, angular6

Recently I came across a slightly different problem. Here's the deal: I'm using an API that requires me to use the same instance across my whole application.

The problem is that my application runs in different tabs and different browsers at the same time and with that in mind my application keeps bootstrapping and creating new instances of the object that I need to use.

I've tried to create a service and inject in the APP module but at some point, a new instance will be generated.

Now I'm trying to use local storage to save the instance but when I retrieve my object I can't call the functions that belong to the object.

```
   let storedObject = localStorage.getItem("storedObject");

  if(storedObject == null) {
        this.storeInstance();
  } else {
      let instancedObj = JSON.parse(storedObject);
      instancedObj.somefunction(); // THIS DOESN'T WORK
  }

  storeInstance() {
       const objThatNeedsToBeTheSame = new TestObject();

       // key / value
       localStorage.setItem("storedObject", JSON.stringify(objThatNeedsToBeTheSame));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use case for firebase real-time API database, and auth by a token.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and I let you know how it goes. Thank you so much. Also, I'm looking at BroadcastChannel API as well.